# Website layout gets messed up on resize

Tags: html, css

Hello good people of Stack Overflow, I am having great troubles with designing a website. I have pretty much finished the first page except for a bit of content, but that's not the question. I am using a PHP include to include a menu on top of each page, to keep it uniform. However, when I resize the window, in any browser, the links will begin wrapping. I think it is an issue with my CSS, or it could be a problem caused by my lack of PHP knowledge.

The link to my website is, [builtbyhabel.net63.net](http://builtbyhabel.net63.net). The code should be able to be seen on the developer tools for whichever browser you are using.

Comment: start by writing valid html\css  http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fbuiltbyhabel.net63.net%2F Its not a guarantee but it significantly increases you chances of being cross-browser compatible

Comment: Post some code and that link doesnt work it links to http://www.000webhost.com/admin-review

Comment: It should be working now, sorry. The web hosting service was checking against their ToS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have your links inside a container without a fixed width.

```
<div><a><a><a></div> <-- this one will contract with the width of your browser

vs

<div><a><a><a></div> <-- CSS div { width:978px; }
```